# Rave Report , Components Dynamically changing

Tags: delphi, rave-reports

I have designed the Salary Certificate format in Rave Report and through Data view(from oracle database) i am getting data and binding.

```
I Have one problem in it  
   For some employees some Allowances should hide (0 Amt Allowances ).
How Can we design Rave report for it.
```

Example
      "Person A Salary Certificate" :                  **Person B Salary Certificate**

```
     **Fixed:**                                 **Fixed:**
         Basic      :   xxx                        Basic      :   xxx
         HRA        :   xxx                        HRA        :   xxx
         Conveyance :   xxx                        Conveyance :   xxx
         DA         :   xxx                        DA         :   xxx 

      **Optional**                             **Optional**
         Management Incent : xxx                   Night Shift Allow  :xxx
         Site Allowance    : xxx                  
         Night Shift Allow  :xxx      

     Please observe the Above 2 persons Salary certificates.

              In Above data, Person B don't have 
                        Management Incentive, 
                        Site  Allowance.
               So Night Shift Allowance Field should move Top.

      How can manage this with single design in Rave Reports.
```

Thanks in Advance.
Raveendra.

Answer (score 0):

If i want to hide something from a report and sometimes to show something based on a condition you can use a DataMirrorSection. There are few steps you need to do.

1. Create a new page where you add the information you want to display(add them as DataMirrorSection).
2. Add a new DataMirrorSection to your mainPage where you want the action to happen.
3. Select the DataField you want as condition ( for example  Allowances )
4. Go to DataMirrors add a new DataMirror ( from Mirrored Section you can select which section you want to display)
5. At field value add the value that the DataField must meet in order to display the selected section.
6. Repeat this for as many values as you want.

Also you can relate to this http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/30331